# Haskell: Syntax Error

Tags: haskell

here is my code for my film Data Type and a database to hold it

```
data Film = String [String] Int [String]
    deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Read) 

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = ["Casino Royale" 
"Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"
2006
"Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"

"Cowboys & Aliens"
"Harrison Ford", "Daniel Craig", "Olivia Wilde"
2011
"Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]
```

and i keep getting this error

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

No idea why its giving me that. ANy help guys?

Comment: You are missing a comma after "Emma" and before "Cowboys & Aliens". Oh, you are missing commas with each newline. Also, you haven't constructed your film values, all you've defined is a list of strings.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has to do with the indentation in your list. Haskell cares a lot about whitespace, and if you continue onto a second line, then you need to indent. Also, make sure that your lists of strings are actually lists. A different issue is that you need a constructor in your data declaration. Try something like this:

```
data Film = Film String [String] Int [String]
    deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Read) 

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [Film "Casino Royale" 
    ["Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"]
    2006
    ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]
    , Film "Cowboys & Aliens"
    ["Harrison Ford", "Daniel Craig", "Olivia Wilde"]
    2011
    ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]]
```